# Javascript confusion

Tags: javascript

```
    var allRapidSpells = $$('input[value^=RSW]');
```

Can anyone tell me what that does?

Comment: there are multiple questions here, that string is xpath, so do you want to know what the xpath does, or what $$() is, or which part are we to tackle first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would venture to guess that you're using [MooTools](http://mootools.net), a JavaScript framework. The [`$$()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Selectors#Selectors) function is used to select an element (or multiple elements) in the DOM.

More specifically, the `$$('input[value^=RSW]');` syntax is selecting all `input` elements whose `value` attribute starts with `RSW`.

Other attribute selectors include:

- `=` : is equal to
- `*=` : contains
- `^=` : starts-with
- `$=` : ends-with
- `!=` : is not equal to
- `~=` : contained in a space separated list
- `|=` : contained in a '-' separated list

**Edit:** It looks as though [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), another JavaScript framework, uses the [same syntax](http://prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar).

Answer (score 2):

Return all inputs that hava value starting with RSW

Answer (score 1):

It calls the function named '$$' with the parameter 'input[value...' and assigns the returnvalue of that function to the var allRapidSpells.

Javascript doesn't consider the '$' to be a reserved character, which jQuery makes excellent use of.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it uses some CSS selectors using some javascript library, the CSS selectors return all **input** tags where the **value** begins **RSW**.

Answer (score 0):

calls a method on the windows object called $$ and passes a string argument to it, which appears to be an xpath expression.

which returns input tags that contain an attribute called value starting with RSW.